# how to display uploaded pictures when creating a post in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working on real estate project in flask. When creating a post I want to be able to add pictures.
I've made function which is using random hex to give unique names to pictures and saves pictures in property_pictures folder. In my route I was able to save uploaded picture in folder and display that picture when reading post but I can't display it when creating post. What I want to do is display images immediately after they've been selected. I would like to be able to add multiple pictures as well. I got stuck with it so I would be grateful for any help!

Here is my code:

```
def save_picture(form_property_pics):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(form_property_pics.filename)
    picture_filename = random_hex + ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(basedir, "static/property_pictures", picture_filename)
    picture_size = (200, 200)
    i = Image.open(form_property_pics)
    i.thumbnail(picture_size)
    i.save(picture_path)
    return picture_filename


@posts.route("/create_post", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def create_post():
    form = FilterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Posts(title=form.title.data,
                     text=form.text.data,
                     county=form.county.data,
                     quadrature=form.quadrature.data,
                     price=form.price.data,
                     property_type=form.property_type.data,
                     property_pictures=form.property_pics.data,
                     user_id=current_user.id)

        if form.property_pics.data:
            file_picture = save_picture(form.property_pics.data)
            post.property_pictures = file_picture

        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your post is created!")

        property_image = url_for("static", filename="property_pictures/" + post.property_pictures)
        return redirect(url_for("core.home", property_image=property_image))
    return render_template("create_post.html", form=form)
```

I tried this in my create_post.html:

```
<img src="{{property_image}}">
```

as well as this (this works in read_post.html):

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='property_pictures/' + post.property_pictures)}}">
```

For adding multiple images i tried using MultipleFileField but it is not working as well as this:

```
{{form.property_pics.label()}} {{form.property_pics(multiple="multiple")}}
```